# Log in and out of iTunes account on separate computer

Tags: itunes, login

Is it possible to use someone else's computer, log out of their iTunes account, log into your own account and access your own library on their computer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, but it takes quite a long time. The simplest way would be to enable iTunes Match on your own computer, and then sign in to the other computer. Another way would be to backup the com.apple.iTunes.plist file in your ~/Library/Preferences directory to an external hard disk, along with the ~/Music/iTunes folder. Then, on the other person's computer, move their com.apple.iTunes.plist file to a safe place (desktop, etc) and copy your com.apple.iTunes.plist file to their Preferences folder (see path above). Then, repeat the process for the iTunes folder in their Music folder.

It's complicated, but it works well for me.

P.S. Don't forget to replace the original person's files.

Comment: I don't think 'enable iTunes Match and then sign in to it on the other computer' constitutes "long time" ;) . OP, even if you don't have iTunes Match you can always download music you've purchased from the iTunes store by clicking on the 'Purchased' tab of the main Music view in iTunes Store, but of course that caveat to that is it's just music you've purchased not a complete library

Comment: Also, want to point out, you don't have to move all the music from the external hard drive to the music folder, this is redundant and could 'take quite a long time' as you say. You can load any iTunes Music Folder from an external HDD, in fact that's how I use mine from a day to day basis, Just change the directory in iTunes preferences

Comment: @soulshined That's very true, thanks for the extra info.